How to embed a power bi report with RLS?
To do this I must obtain a token from a Microsoft API
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenatId}/oauth2/token
The necessary x-www-form-urlendcoded are:
- client_id: '',
- client_secret: '',
- grant_type: 'password',
- resource: 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
- username: '',
- password: '',
- scope: 'openid'

With the accessToken obtained, make another request to embed the report
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports/{reportId}/GenerateToken
Body
{
"accessLevel": "View",
"identities": [
    {
        "username": "user@example.com",
        "roles": [ "Dynamic"],
        "datasets": [ "" ]
    }
  ]
}

I can't replicate that same process in frontend with Angular and PrimerNg
I have this method
  reportConfig: IReportEmbedConfiguration = {
    type: 'report',
    embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: '',
    settings: {
      background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
    },
  };

  embedReport() {
    if (this.data) {
      this.reportConfig = {
        ...this.reportConfig,
        id: '',
        accessToken: this.data.accessToken,
      };
    } else {
      console.error('Data is undefined');
    }
  }

HTML
<div class="card">
  <div class="report-container">
    <powerbi-report
      [embedConfig]="reportConfig"
      [eventHandlers]="eventHandlersMap"
    ></powerbi-report>
  </div>
</div>


Could you please edit your question and include more details like which error you faced?
